# How to discard a match if the string contains a certain word in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex: `start([\s\S]*?)end`.

---

The regex should only match between `start` and `end`.

```
start text text text end
```

And discard matches containing `forbidden` between `start` and `end`.

```
start text text text forbidden end
```

I have tried adding a negative lookahead but i can't get it to work.

Comment: You should write regex for matching strings with forbidden. So if match not found then it is valid string

Comment: While `start((?:(?!forbidden)[\s\S])*?)end` is the regex you seek, I'd rather suggest filtering the matches you get now with the `forbidden` substring.

Comment: Thank you, i will filter them out. My apologies for the duplicate question, should i delete it?

Answer (score 0):

With RegX:

```js
var str='start text text text forbidden end';
var output = str.replace(/ *\b\S*?forbidden\S*\b/g, '');
console.log(output);
```

Without regx:

```js
var str = "start text text text forbidden end".replace('forbidden','');
console.log(str);
```